# Is it possible to query an SQL Pivot report and join the output in another select statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, view, relationship

I have a pivot type report in SQL (created as a view).

Ticket numbers are ROWS while Ticket Statuses are COLUMNS.

The values in the data are time stamps (hh:mm:ss) of the total time a ticket is spend in that status.

Sample of SQL Pivot view (**Note: All statuses are not listed (see SQL pivot Query for all**):

```
ticket_number   closed    completed   new       waiting-1   
22              0:00:00   0:00:00     0:00:00   0:00:00
32              0:00:00   0:00:00     6:00:01   0:00:00
```

**SQL Pivot Query:**

**v_pivottime**

```
WITH t AS (
    select 
        ticket_number,
        ISNULL(status,'null') status,
        update_date,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number ORDER BY update_date) rn
    from xxx.dbo.report
), s AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.ticket_number,
        t1.status,
        t1.update_date,
        t2.update_date prevdate,
        case when t2.status=t1.status then DATEDIFF(s, t2.update_date, t1.update_date) end dif
    FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.ticket_number=t2.ticket_number AND t1.rn=t2.rn+1
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ticket_number,
        [status],
        cast(dateadd(s,sum(dif),0) as time(0)) [time]
    FROM s
    GROUP BY ticket_number,status )  src
PIVOT
(
  min([time])
  for [status] in ([Closed], [Complete], [New], [Waiting-1], [Waiting-2], [Waiting-3], [stoptime], [Research-1], [Research-2], [Resolved], [Special Request], [Opened Request], [null])
) piv;
```

**Queried view (below) I would like to add (join?) the pivot output to, and add status names across the top (columns) as well as the value output in hh:mm:ss**

**v_last_update**

```
select
        ctr1.ticket_number,
        ctr1.status,
        ctr1.create_date,
        ctr1.created_by,
        ctr1.customer,
        ctr1.description,
        ctr1.update_sequence,
        ctr1.update_date        
FROM    
        xx.dbo.report ctr1
JOIN    (
                select ticket_number as ticket_number_d,
                MAX(update_date) as max_update_date,
                MAX(update_sequence) as max_ update_sequence
                from xx.dbo.report
                group by ticket_number
        ) ctr2

ON      ctr1.ticket_number = ctr2.ticket_number_d
AND     ctr1.update_date = ctr2.max_update_date
AND     ctr1.update_sequence = ctr2.max_update_sequence
WHERE   customer <> ‘Bread’
ORDER BY max_update_date ASC;
```

*Would like to see if there is a way I can somewhat perform a vlookup type deal from the ticket number in the v_last_update query and add columns to the end of the columns in the output.  Would like to add a column for each status and insert the timing of that tickets status.  Is this possible its driving me crazy!

Thank you!

-P

Comment: Assuming, that all your queries deliver as expected, just create a VIEW or (inline!)-TVF from your pivot query and join it as if it was a table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Addition to my comment you could let the Pivot part be a CTE as well:

(untested)

```
WITH t AS (
    select 
        ticket_number,
        ISNULL(status,'null') status,
        update_date,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_number ORDER BY update_date) rn
    from xxx.dbo.report
), s AS (
    SELECT 
        t1.ticket_number,
        t1.status,
        t1.update_date,
        t2.update_date prevdate,
        case when t2.status=t1.status then DATEDIFF(s, t2.update_date, t1.update_date) end dif
    FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.ticket_number=t2.ticket_number AND t1.rn=t2.rn+1
)
,pivotPart AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ticket_number,
            [status],
            cast(dateadd(s,sum(dif),0) as time(0)) [time]
        FROM s
        GROUP BY ticket_number,status )  src
    PIVOT
    (
      min([time])
      for [status] in ([Closed], [Complete], [New], [Waiting-1], [Waiting-2], [Waiting-3], [stoptime], [Research-1], [Research-2], [Resolved], [Special Request], [Opened Request], [null])
    ) piv
)
select
        ctr1.ticket_number,
        ctr1.status,
        ctr1.create_date,
        ctr1.created_by,
        ctr1.customer,
        ctr1.description,
        ctr1.update_sequence,
        ctr1.update_date,
        pivotPart.*        
FROM    
        xx.dbo.report ctr1
JOIN pivotPart ON ctr1.ticket_number=pivotPart.ticket_number
JOIN    (
                select ticket_number as ticket_number_d,
                MAX(update_date) as max_update_date,
                MAX(update_sequence) as max_ update_sequence
                from xx.dbo.report
                group by ticket_number
        ) ctr2

ON      ctr1.ticket_number = ctr2.ticket_number_d
AND     ctr1.update_date = ctr2.max_update_date
AND     ctr1.update_sequence = ctr2.max_update_sequence
WHERE   customer <> ‘Bread’
ORDER BY max_update_date ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you Shungo!  The query works, but there are no columns showing the timestamps from the pivot

Comment: @Panthersfball234, In the "pivotPart" you select ticket_number, status and time, above you take with "SELECT *" just these three... Don't know what other information you need... btw: If you want to have the pivot with more than one column it gets very tricky. Please vote up and/or mark as accepted if helpful or go on asking...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, figured it out which was way easier than I thought.

What I did was turn the select statement AND pivot query into separate views.  After that, joined the select view with the pivot view ON ticket_number.  It returned all of the columns in the pivot view inline with the select statement ticket numbers.  Spot checked and its on point!

Thank you everyone for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As it was my comment and my answer which brought you on the right path it would be very kind of you to upvote my answer and/ or mark as accepted, thx!

Comment: Done :)  Thank you so much again